# split object to object arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Hello I'm stuck transforming this object to an object array.

There are the number and reason field, which are currently an ',' separated string. They should be exploded into their own object. The exampel dataset and what I want to archive can be seen in the codesnippet below.

```js
// start value
const data = {
  date: "2021-09-07 10:28:34,2021-09-08 14:45:22",
  startDate: "2021-09-07 00:00:00,2021-09-08 14:45:22"
  id: "111111"
  number: "1,9"
  reason: "Autres,Autres"

}

// what I want to archive:
  const res = [{
    date: "2021-09-07 10:28:34",
    startDate: "2021-09-07 00:00:00",
    id: 11111,
    number: 1,
    reason: "Autres"
  } {
    date: "2021-09-08 14:45:22",
    startDate: "2021-09-08 14:45:22",
    id: 11111,
    number: 9,
    reason: "Autres"
  }]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? `.split()` combined with some loops should already get you into the right direction.

Comment: @VincentMenzel Why did you completely re-write the question? What's an _"object array"_? And how does a snippet without any output/result but with a syntax error improve this question?

Comment: I would like to fix them however the queue is currently full so I have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

1. Project the original object with string-combined-columns into an object with [splitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) columns as arrays using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

   1a. extract column names from original object by [filtering out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `id` column.

   1b. In the process of projection, count the amount of rows.
2. Iterate over rows using the above counter, generating a new object for each row, taking relevant column value using current iteration index.

   ```js
   const original = {
     date: "2021-09-07 10:28:34,2021-09-08 14:45:22",
     startDate: "2021-09-07 00:00:00,2021-09-08 14:45:22",
     id: "111111",
     number: "1,9",
     reason: "Autres,Autres"
   };

   function split(obj) {
     const columnNames = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key !== "id");
     const singleWithSplitted = columnNames.reduce((result, columnName) => {
       const splittedArray = obj[columnName].split(",");
       return ({
         rowsCount: Math.max(result.rowsCount, splittedArray.length),
         table: { ...result.table,
           [columnName]: splittedArray
         }
       });
     }, {
       rowsCount: 0
     });
     const arr = [];
     for (i = 0; i < singleWithSplitted.rowsCount; i++) {
       const result = {
         id: obj.id
       };
       columnNames.forEach((columnName) => {
         result[columnName] = singleWithSplitted.table[columnName][i];
       });
       arr.push(result);
     };
     return arr;
   }
   console.log(split(original));
   ```